# do,while in bash

Tags: wireless, networking, bash, ethernet, log

I want to get RX and TX from each network adapter, so to get RX and TX from one network adapter, i used this commands :

```
cat /proc/net/dev | grep 'wlan0' |awk  '{if ($2) print $2}' |  awk -v var="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %r")" '{print  $1"&",var";"}' >> /opt/baran/log/baran_RX_usage_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d");
cat /proc/net/dev | grep 'wlan0' |awk  '{if ($10) print $10}' |  awk -v var="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %r")" '{print  $1"&",var";"}' >> /opt/baran/log/baran_TX_usage_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d");
```

As you see, i put result into a file with date (daily).
I want this in a while loop to get every netword adapter instead of just wlan0, so we must have some log files like :

```
opt/baran/log/baran_TX_usage_wlan0_2014-01-01
opt/baran/log/baran_RX_usage_wlan0_2014-01-01
opt/baran/log/baran_TX_usage_eth0_2014-01-01
opt/baran/log/baran_RX_usage_eth0_2014-01-01
opt/baran/log/baran_TX_usage_eth1_2014-01-01
opt/baran/log/baran_RX_usage_eth1_2014-01-01
opt/baran/log/baran_TX_usage_eth2_2014-01-01
opt/baran/log/baran_RX_usage_eth2_2014-01-01
opt/baran/log/baran_TX_usage_eth3_2014-01-01
opt/baran/log/baran_RX_usage_eth3_2014-01-01
```

As you can see, i have one wireless adapter and 4 eth, and i want log file for each of them daily.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could base your loop on the contents of the /sys/class/net/ directory?

```
for iface in /sys/class/net/*
do 
  grep "${iface##*/}" /proc/net/dev ...
done
```

If you need to exclude the `lo` interface you could either enable extended bash globs (`shopt -s extglob`) to allow you to use negation, or just limit the matches to eth and wlan device names

```
for iface in /sys/class/net/!(lo) ...

for iface in /sys/class/net/{eth,wlan}* ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a continuously-running loop by using `true` as the condition.

```
while true
do
    # Insert commands here
    sleep 5 # wait for 5 seconds
done
```

However, if you want it to get the TX and RX just once per day, or once every few hours, you might want to set up a cron job instead.

Comment: thanks my friend, but i want a while that make loop in X times and X is number of network adapters. another thing is that i need to access to network adapter name in while.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in /etc/cron.daily, give it execute privileges:

```
sudo touch /etc/cron.daily/tx-rx-counter
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/tx-rx-counter
```

then edit it and paste this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for iface in $(tail -n+3 /proc/net/dev | cut -d: -f1); do
    grep $iface /proc/net/dev | awk '{if ($2) print $2}'   | awk -v var="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %r")" '{print  $1"&",var";"}' >> /opt/baran/log/baran_RX_usage_$iface_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
    grep $iface /proc/net/dev | awk '{if ($10) print $10}' | awk -v var="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %r")" '{print  $1"&",var";"}' >> /opt/baran/log/baran_TX_usage_$iface_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
done
```

It will run daily at 6:25 AM.